# Unable to create hypertables with rules

Tags: timescaledb

I am unable to create a hypertable on a table that already contains pre-existing rules, or even if I create a hypertable first and then try to add rules on that table it does not work.

Errors listed below:

```
ERROR:  hypertables do not support rules
DETAIL:  Table "trafficsummary07112019" has attached rules, which do not work on hypertables.
HINT:  Remove the rules before calling create_hypertable

ERROR:  hypertables do not support rules (When trying to add rule after creating hypertable)
```

This was working fine on old version of postgresql (V9) and TimeScaleDB (0.10.1).

Would appreciate if anyone can help with this.

Comment: Can you clarify which version of TimescaleDB were you using with rules?

Comment: Edited original post. I was using TimeScaleDB 0.10.1 earlier and rules were working fine on that version.

Comment: Rules are disabled in later version of TimescaleDB. Can you reformulate them into triggers? In general PostgreSQL recommends to use triggers instead of rules.